# CSS3 Style Check box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, css, jquery-mobile

am trying to get to this particular image below using pure css3,
[image]

How it works: The app works in such a way that once the toggle button on the page is switched on,check boxes are activated and user can either check or un-check the boxes just like the image below.functional wise, the app is done but am having problem's getting the CSS aligned so it can look like the image below. kindly refer to this for a working example and my progress so far http://jsfiddle.net/YGeZD/

Comment: why don't you use Jquery mobile? I think it is good.

Comment: Hi Bunlong Am not so familiar with Jquery that's why i have to use CSS. can you shed some light or help me out in using jquery to solve this problem. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My only solution for you would be hide the checkbox by setting its opacity to zero, then handle your visual on/off states through a  element with a background image, like the following:

```
<div class="checkbox_frame">
 <input type="checkbox" value="None" />
 <span class="state"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.checkbox_frame {
position: relative;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
width: 30px; height: 30px;
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + .state {
display: block;
width: 30px; 
height: 30px;
background: url('http://i153.photobucket.com/albums/s229/fluffyshuffle/error1.png') center center no-repeat;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .state {
background: url('http://i153.photobucket.com/albums/s229/fluffyshuffle/tick1.png') center center no-repeat;
}
```

** Revised

​

Comment: Hi Shawn, i have added the above codes accordingly but still not working. i just updated another jsfiddle to show you the current edited version with the codes you gave me. http://jsfiddle.net/DauhQ/ i changed the off.png and on.png to links. if you dont mind, send me the corrected version using jsfiddle.net thanks

Comment: Hi Apulo, perhaps this will set you on the right track: http://jsfiddle.net/DauhQ/3/

Comment: Thanks Shawn Wernig, you are the man, am happy its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can see [jquery mobile document](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/) and try to play around with it I think it is not hard to learn it. and I will give you a demo later, cheer !!!

Comment: Thanks Bunlong, i will be waiting. am still trying to find my way around Jquery mobile Docs..